# Iterate Checkbox property with ForEach without using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, foreach

The code below iterates through all of the checkboxes on a form, inverting the .Checked state of each checkbox.

It it possible to avoid using LINQ to do this?

```
public void TickChecker()
    {
        foreach (CheckBox con in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            con.Checked ^= true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already got answers but just a suggestion: I think `con.Checked = !con.Checked` is more readable than using the XOR operator to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has long supported two operators to check the type of an object: is and as. C# 7 adds a new way to use the is operator that combines is with basic patterns to provide an alternative for as. So you can it on your `foreach`:

```
foreach (Control con in Controls)
{
    if (con is CheckBox checkBox)
    {
       checkBox.Checked ^= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Once I changed .IsChecked to .Checked, This worked with the fewest layers of brackets, so you get the tickmark.

Comment: @Alan `IsChecked` sounds like WPF, if you are using Winforms, you should specify it with a tag under your post

Comment: @MongZhu 

Thank you for the advice.  I am using System.Windows.Forms, and have added the tag.

Comment: may be you should mention that you are using pattern matching which will only work from C# 7 upwards. in older versions this will not work

Comment: @MongZhu mentioned !

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public void TickChecker()
{
    foreach (var con in Controls)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = con as CheckBox;
        if (null != checkBox)
        {
            checkBox.Checked ^= true;
        }
    }
}
```